# Storing JSON REST response in object

Tags: c#, json, rest, themoviedb-api

I am new to `C#` and I am trying to work out how to store my `HTTPResponseMessage` in an object.

```
static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("search/tv?api_key=MY_KEYa&query=hawaii%20five%20o&first_air_date_year=2010");                

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {


                // What to do here..?


            }
        }
    }
```

I used this site (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) for the above code.

Using this website (http://json2csharp.com/), I created the following class:

```
class TVShowDTO
{
    public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string original_name { get; set; }
    public string first_air_date { get; set; }
    public List<string> origin_country { get; set; }
    public string poster_path { get; set; }
    public double popularity { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int vote_average { get; set; }
    public int vote_count { get; set; }
}
```

API Response:

```
{
   page: 1
   results: [1]
   0:  {
   backdrop_path: "/mAXpHFDTMHvJt7WdibFWdbRsdCG.jpg"
   id: 32798
   original_name: "Hawaii Five-0"
   first_air_date: "2010-09-20"
   origin_country: [1]
   0:  "US"
   -
   poster_path: "/hO4BgEJhGIrFJ7f00sR6ZcdNB6y.jpg"
   popularity: 1.06099324148627
   name: "Hawaii Five-0"
   vote_average: 7.3
   vote_count: 6
   }-
   -
   total_pages: 1
   total_results: 1
}
```

Here is a link to the `API` I am trying to access: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/reference/search/searchtv/get

Do I need to get the `response` as a `string` first? Because the examples I have seen of this on SO, seem to use an input `string`.

I haven't been able to work this out as when I print `response.Content`, it just returns `"System.Net.Http.StreamContent"`

Any guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to get a string of the response:

```
string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Then, you can use a tool like Json.NET from NUGET to deserialize to your object:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TVShowDTO>(responseContent);
```